# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre hacer "extends Comparable<E>" y "implements Comparable<E>" en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy viendo en varios programas la implementación de la clase Comparable, pero en algunos la he visto usarse como interfaz

```
public class Class implements Comparable<E> ...
```

y en otros como una clase padre

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> boolean estaOrdenada (PositionList<E> list);
```

¿Hay alguna diferencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si hay diferencia.

En el primer caso se usa `implements` porque es la palabra clave que se utiliza para indicar que una clase implementa los métodos abstractos de una interfaz (en este caso la interfaz Comparable). Una interfaz es muy parecida a una clase abstracta (no se pueden crear objetos nuevos de esta clase, hay que heredar de ella para poder instanciarla) en la que todos sus métodos son abstractos (ningún método tiene implementación por lo que el la clase que hereda de esa interfaz debe implementar o hacer abstractos todos los métodos de su clase padre).

Nota: A partir de Java 8 hay un tipo de interfaz funcional que puede implementar algunos métodos también con alguna limitación.

Nota2: Como nos menciona además @E. Betanzos:

> Las interfaces en java pueden tener todo tipo de métodos: abstractos
>   (los de toda la vida), estáticos y por defecto (desde java 8); y
>   privados (desde java 9). Aunque se parezcan cada vez más una clase
>   abstracta, lo cierto es que no lo son. Estos nuevos tipos de métodos
>   en las interfaces están ideados para usarse, sobre todo, en interfaces
>   funcionales.

Esto es un mecanismo que utiliza Java para poder realizar una herencia múltiple con algunas limitaciones. También puedes heredar de otra clase con la palabra clave `extends`, pero siempre se heredeando de una clase en vez de una interfaz, y solamente se puede heredar de una clase (mientras que se pueden implementar múltiples interfaces).

En el segundo caso lo que se indica es que la función estaOrdenada devuelve un objeto de una clase E. No se especifica que clase es E, pero tiene que cumplir que herede de alguna forma (mediante extends o mediante implements) de una clase o interfaz que sea Comparable. En este caso no se pone nunca > aunque comparable sea una interfaz.

Con ejemplos un poco menos abstractos, imagínate que tienes estas clases

```
public class Ave {}
public class Mamifero {}

public interface PuedeVolar {}
public interface PuedeNadar {}

public class Aguila extends Ave implements PuedeVolar {}
public class Pato extends Ave implements PuedeVolar, PuedeNadar {}
public class Murcielago extends Mamifero implements PuedeVolar {}
```

En estos ejemplo tienes ejemplos de pseudo-herencia múltiple con la palabra clave implements.

Si tuviesemos una función así:

```
public <T extends PuedeVolar> T funcion1();
```

Esa función podría devolver tanto como un Aguila, como un Pato como un Murcielago (fijate que aquí uso extends pese a que PuedeVolar es un interfaz)

Esta función solo podría devolver un Pato:

```
public <T extends PuedeNadar> T funcion2();
```

Y esta función solo podría devolver un Pato o un Aguila:

```
public <T extends Ave> T funcion3();
```

Volviendo al caso que comentas con la función estaOrdenada, el motivo por el que E tiene que heredar de alguna forma de la interfaz Comparable es porque seguramente dicha función va a llamar en algún momento al método compareTo sobre cada elemento de esa lista.

Por último añadir, que cuando una interfaz hereda de otra interfaz, se utiliza `extends` en lugar de `implements`

Comment: Las interfaces en java pueden tener todo tipo de métodos: abstractos (los de toda la vida), estáticos y por defecto (desde java 8); y privados (desde java 9). Aunque se parezcan cada vez más una clase abstracta, lo cierto es que no lo son. Estos nuevos tipos de métodos en las interfaces están ideados para usarse, sobre todo, en interfaces funcionales.

Comment: Gracias, no conocía la parte de los métodos privados desde Java 9. Te voy a citar directamente en la edición ya que lo has explicado muy bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Ésta es una de las (pocas) inconsistencias en la sintaxis de Java: Cuando se definieron los *genéricos*, se obvió la palabra `implements`, usando siempre `extends`. Creo que es más sencillo verlo con ejemplos:

Supongamos una interfaz InterfaceA:

```
interface InterfaceA { ... }
```

Podemos crear una nueva interfaz que extiende a InterfaceA:

```
interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA { ... }
```

O podemos crear una clase que la implementa:

```
class ClassA implements InterfaceA { ... }
```

Pero cuando trabajamos con genéricos, no sabemos si el genérico declarado `E` es una clase o una interfaz, así que se decidió usar siempre extends para indicar que E cumple una condición:

```
void <E extends InterfaceA>hagoAlgo(E param);
```

Donde `E` podría ser `ClassA` o `InterfaceB`